# cuda printf and __syncthreads ordering

Tags: cuda, printf

Cuda printf does not seem to respect __syncthreads(), even within the same block.  In particular, I would expect that if my threads print out something before calling __syncthreads and something else after, then I would see all of the before prints followed by all of the after prints.  That's not what I'm seeing, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  Here's my code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#define ROUND_UP(x) (((x)&1) + ((x)>>1))
__global__ void test()
{
  int t = threadIdx.x, last = blockDim.x;
  int offset = ROUND_UP(last);

  while (last > 1 && t + offset < last) {
    offset = ROUND_UP(offset);
    last = ROUND_UP(last);
    __syncthreads();
    if (t == 33 || t == 64)
      printf("A: t = %d, last = %d\n", t, last);
  }
  while (last > 1) {
    last = ROUND_UP(last);
    __syncthreads();
    if (t == 33 || t == 64)
      printf("B: t = %d, last = %d\n", t, last);
  }
}

int main()
{
  test<<<1,66>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
B: t = 64, last = 33
B: t = 64, last = 17
B: t = 33, last = 33
B: t = 64, last = 9
B: t = 33, last = 17
B: t = 64, last = 5
B: t = 33, last = 9
B: t = 64, last = 3
B: t = 33, last = 5
B: t = 64, last = 2
B: t = 33, last = 3
B: t = 64, last = 1
B: t = 33, last = 2
B: t = 33, last = 1
```

As I read this, thread 64 has exited the __syncthreads twice before thread 33 has entered it a second time.  How is this possible?

Comment: You're using syncthreads in a conditional block that depends on threadIdx.  I suspect your code is likely broken in this respect.

Comment: @Robert, the loops are constructed with the intent that syncthreads will be called the same number of times regardless of the threadIdx.  The the ROUND_UP macro halves its input, rounding up, so last goes from 66, 33, 17, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1.  Each time, synthreads is called once, although which while loop it is called from varies by thread idx.

Comment: @JonathanShaw: Sorry, that was hard to find on a mobile phone screen. Keep in mind that memory transactions in CUDA are "fire and forget", and the order in which the memory controller clears transaction requests is undefined, That might effect the order you see. In general, using printf in the way you are trying is probably not recommended

Comment: So are you just guessing that that is a valid approach to using `__syncthreads()` ?  If you read [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions), I think you'll discover that "__syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block".  It sounds to me like your condition does not evaluate identically across the entire threadblock.  Perhaps you should run cuda-memcheck with the synccheck option on your code.

Comment: @talonmies, I would expect prints from different threads to come out in random order, but are you saying that I should not expect that this order will respect syncthreads properly?

Comment: @Robert, good call!  That seems to be the issue.  I merged the loops so there is only one call to syncthreads, and the problem has vanished.  Thanks, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Would someone care to add an answer?

Comment: I spent some time looking for a duplicate.  Haven't found one yet that just provides an answer that says "syncthreads is not allowed in conditional code" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions),

> __syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block

OP's code appears to violate this requirement.  According to OP's statements, refactoring the code to address this caused the puzzling `printf` observation to go away.

If there are concerns in this area, the [cuda-memcheck](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#synccheck-tool) tool offers a `synccheck` option which can be used to look for invalid usage of `__syncthreads()` in divergent code.